# What is the namespace to use for adding JSP taglib support into facelets pages?

Tags: jsf, facelets, code-injection, javabeans

Something like the following

```
     xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
```

seems to not work, any hint? alternatively how can I inject beans into JSF lifecycle flow at startup without the filter usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What is the namespace to use for
>   adding JSP taglib support into
>   facelets pages?**

You cannot. Facelets are not JSPs and do not use JSP tag libraries. From the [project page](https://facelets.dev.java.net/):

> *The difference is under the hood where
>   **all the burden of the JSP Vendor API
>   is removed** to more greatly enhance JSF
>   performance and provide easy
>   plug-and-go development.*

---

> **how can I inject beans into JSF**

Add them to your *[WEB-INF/faces-config.xml](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnawp.html)* file using *[managed-bean](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaqm.html#bnaqo)* elements.